# Unfortuntely My App has stopped

Tags: java, android

I was developing an app named "Health Analyzer" but when I run it on my physical device it says:

> Unfortunately, Health Analyzer has stopped

I think that the main problem is with the intent since the splash screen loads properly but then it shows the error.

This is my code. Please check it and help me.

**Code in Main Activity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.pdsuck);
        imageView.setAnimation(animation);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}




**XML code of activity2**


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:backgroundTint="@drawable/live"
    android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
    tools:context="com.example.india.pi_softs.Main2Activity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:background="?attr/colorControlActivated"
        android:hint="Enter your height (m)"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.259" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="232dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:hint="Enter your weight (kg)"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.754" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="322dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Your Analysis Will  Apper Here"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="131dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:foreground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:shadowColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Analysis"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:text="Check Now"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/colorPressedHighlight"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.499"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.186" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Error in Logcat**

```
02-03 20:33:41.322 4408-4408/com.example.india.healthanalyzer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.india.healthanalyzer, PID: 4408
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.india.healthanalyzer/com.example.india.healthanalyzer.Main2Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.india.healthanalyzer.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.india.healthanalyzer.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:11) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.india.healthanalyzer.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:11) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/live.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f060056: .xml extension required
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:4417)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:4358)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:487)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4561)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:591)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:587)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:583)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.india.healthanalyzer.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:11) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Something wrong with your layout, are you declaring the views correctly in the XML layout file?

Comment: post your xml code and make sure you have the drawable live placed in drawable and cross-check its file extension. should be android supported image format or .xml format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your error: `Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/live.png`

Looks like that image does not exist or is referenced incorrectly.